# Sum Only Visible Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, formula, subtotal

I have data in Cells `B2:ZZ2` and I am hiding several of the cells.  I want a way to `SUM()` the data in the visible cells only.  I have tried `SUM()` and `SUBTOTAL(109)` however, I am not getting the sum I am after.  If you take a look at image 1, it shows I get all 0 returned from my formula.  And I show my formula in the address bar.  Image 2 shows my desired output.  What formula can I use to get my desired ouput?

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the "numbers" you want to sum may actually be text, which Excel does not see as numbers and you will get 0.   Try running a text to columns on the cells containing the data, even though there is nothing to split to another column.   Also, subtotal only excludes hidden rows for some reason, not columns.  I am not sure why they designed it that way, but they did.   I found some VBA to create a customer UDF, here:   [link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/655374-subtotal-column-hiding.html) if that helps you at all.

Comment: That did the trick, but the formula is including data in hidden cells.

Comment: see my answer to ensure hidden cells are not included in your SUBTOTAL @nospaceshuttleleftinthisnatio

Comment: The sumtotal formula should work whether you enter it before or after.   How are the hidden cells hidden?   Are they manually hidden or hidden as the result of a filter?   If manually hidden, is it possible to achieve the same results using a filter (subtotal is more reliable when used with a filter, than manually hidden, even when using the 10x type)

Comment: Also, try unhiding the hidden area and rehiding them.  Cells can be resized to the point they appear hidden, but actually aren't.

Comment: Actually, after a moment to take this in, I realized the problem is you are hiding columns......not rows.   Subtotal only excludes hidden rows for some reason, not columns.  I am not sure why they designed it that way, but they did.   I found some VBA to create a customer UDF, here:   [link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/655374-subtotal-column-hiding.html) if that helps you at all.

Comment: @Fred - that link did the trick thank you so much!  If you update your answer to include it, I will gladly accept.

Answer (score 0):

Enter your `=SUBTOTAL` formula *after* the cells are hidden to ensure they are not included in the `SUM`.

```
=SUBTOTAL(109,B2:ZZ2)
```

Comment: I don't follow you.  Even if I move the formula to say Cell A14 (where there is no data) it still produces a 0.

Comment: is your SUBTOTAL's ref1 correct after moving the formula?

Comment: you shouldn't be getting a 0, if anything your sum should be too much if it is including hidden cells

Comment: it was a 2 step fix, 1 I had to move the total column out of the range I was subtotaling() and 2 I had to do the text to columns.  But to answer your direct ? yes the cell reference has been updated.